# A formal definition of the average and median functions.

Tags: statistics, terminology

In most probability and statistics books, the average of a sequence of numbers is not stated in a formal way. Neither is the median. So, my question is this. Let $S$ be the set of all non-empty finite sequences of real numbers. How does one formally define the functions $average: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $median: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you mean?  The average of $\{s_i\}_{i=1}^n=\frac 1n\times \sum s_i$.  The median is the middle number if $n$ is odd (and the $s_i$ are in order $s_1≤s_2≤\cdots ≤s_n$). an it is the average of the two middle numbers if $n$ is even.  Was there some particular situation you were concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like using the word "average," so I assume you're referring to the arithmetic mean.

In $S$ (which you have specified as a set of all non-empty finite sequences of real numbers), consider an arbitrary sequence of some integer length $0 < n < \infty$, say $s_1, \dots, s_n$. Then the arithmetic mean $a: S \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$a(s_1, \dots, s_n) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_i\text{.}$$
Now for the median - suppose we order the sequence $s_1, \dots, s_n$ in ascending order, yielding values $s_{(1)}, \dots, s_{(n)}$ so that $s_{(1)} \leq \cdots \leq s_{(n)}$. (These are known as [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).) Then the median $m: S \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as follows:
$$m(s_1, \dots, s_n) = \begin{cases}
s_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)}, & n \text{ odd} \\
\frac{1}{2}\left[s_{(n/2)}+s_{(n/2 + 1)}\right], & n \text{ even.}
\end{cases}$$